# Autokey (autokey-qt) freezes and won't insert text

Tags: kubuntu, qt, autokey

Per some suggestions on here and lifehacker, I began using autokey.

It worked great for a week, but as of today it now

- hangs when I try to enter name new phrases.
- usually won't close when I push the 'x' in my window manger

and

- no longer responds to my abbreviation phrases.

I've added a few phrases and rebooted since my last successful attempt at using it.

Another user reported a similar problem for the [gtk version of autokey](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364608/autokey-not-working-in-saucy).

The results of running it from the command line seems to show some exception errors:

```
Exception in thread KeypressHandler-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/iomediator.py", line 202, in run
    target.handle_keypress(rawKey, modifiers, key, windowName, windowClass)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/service.py", line 179, in handle_keypress
    currentInput, windowInfo, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/service.py", line 304, in __checkTextMatches
    if item.check_input(buffer, windowInfo):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/model.py", line 732, in check_input
    abbr = self._should_trigger_abbreviation(buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/model.py", line 131, in _should_trigger_abbreviation
    if self.__checkInput(buffer, abbr):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/model.py", line 144, in __checkInput
    stringBefore, typedAbbr, stringAfter = self._partition_input(buffer, abbr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/model.py", line 191, in _partition_input
    stringBefore, typedAbbr, stringAfter = currentString.rpartition(abbr)
ValueError: empty separator
```

[Full log here](http://pastebin.com/LQ7jZ8Za)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @minerz029 thanks for that edit; wish there was a way to +1 it as it's insightful to see how an answer should cause a revision to the data in the question, and how to deal with long log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with auto key some more I noticed that one of my 'Abbreviations' had a comma appended to it and was enclosed by brackets: `[<myabbreviation>,]`

Upon further inspection, this 'Phrase' rule had an second, extra blank 'abbreviation' enabled that when deleted caused the bracketing to disappear.

Since deleting this extra blank 'abbreviation' Autokey seems to now run be running perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This is my change to the offending code:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/model.py

```
def _should_trigger_abbreviation(self, buffer):
    """
    Checks whether, based on the settings for the abbreviation and the given input,
    the abbreviation should trigger.

    @param buffer Input buffer to be checked (as string)
    """
    for abbr in self.abbreviations:
        if abbr == "":
            continue
        if self.__checkInput(buffer, abbr):
            return True
```